# PHP-MYSQL: Not able to fetch multiple record from database into word file

Tags: php, mysql, ms-word

I have to download the records from database into a word file. But m not able to do so as whenever i add while loop around the table it is giving me error.

My code is working fine when i fetch single records.
Can anbody provide me the way to fetch multiple records.

Here is my Code:

```
  <?php


   include('dbcon.php');

   if($_GET['id']!='')

$id=$_GET['id'];

    $party_name=mysql_query("select * FROM tb_party Where party_id='".$id."' ");
    $party_name_row=mysql_fetch_array($party_name);


    $sample_text1 = $party_name_row['party_name'];




        $party_details="select * from tb_party_rate_entry
                    where party_id='$id'";
                    $query_details=mysql_query($party_details);
                    $row_details=mysql_fetch_array($query_details);



                    $word_xmlns = "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
                    xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
                    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40′";

                   $word_xml_settings = "<xml><w:WordDocument>
                   <w:View>Print</w:View><w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom></w:WordDocument></xml>";

                   $word_landscape_style = 
                   "@page {size:8.5in 11.0in; margin:0.5in 0.31in 0.42in 0.25in;
                    }  div.Section1{page:Section1;}";

                   $word_landscape_headinh="{font-size:15px; }";


                  $word_landscape_div_imf='
                 <img  src="http://silverevents.net/user_image/' .$sample_text1 . '"  
                       height="150" width="150"/>';



                     $word_landscape_div_start = "<div class='Section1′>";

                  $word_landscape_div_end = "</div>";

                  $content = '<html '.$word_xmlns.'>
        <head>
                     <title>Party Rate Report</title>'
                     .$word_xml_settings.'<style type="text/css">
        '.$word_landscape_style.' table,td 
                     {border:1px solid #FFFFFF; width:200px; color:#CCC;} </style>
        </head>
        <body>'.$word_landscape_div_start  . 
                    '<table style="width:500px; color:#000000; 
                    margin:0 0 50px 100px; font-family: Arial Black, Gadget, 
                    sans-serif; font-size:24px;"><tr><td> Party Rate Report </td>
                    </tr></table></br>

        <table style="width:700px;font-size:15px;font-family: 
                     Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif;">

        <tr>

        <td width="180">
            Party Name : '.  $party_name_row['party_name'] . '
        </td>

        <td width="250">
        Address : '.  $party_name_row['party_address'] . '
        </td>

        <td width="150">
        Phone : '.   $party_name_row['phone_no']. '
        </td>
        </tr>


        </table><br/>   
        <table style="width:700px; color:#00000; margin:22px 0 0 0px; 
                     font- family:Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana; 
                    font-size:15px;  border1px solid #666;">
        <tr>
        <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Zone</td>
        <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> 
                     Delivery Mode          
                     </td>
        <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Doc Type </td>
        <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Weight slot </td>
        <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Weight Unit </td>
        <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Flat </td>
        <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Price </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
         <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">' .
                     $row_details['zone_id']. '</td>
                   <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.
                    $row_details['delivery_mode_id'].'
                   </td>
                 <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'. 
                  $row_details['doc_type_id'].'</td>    
                 <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'. 
                   $row_details['weight_slot_id'].'</td>    
                 <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.
                 $row_details['weight_measure_id'].'</td>   
           <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.
              $row_details['flat'].'</td>   
           <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.   
            $row_details['price' ] . '</td>         
        </tr>


        </table></br>' . $word_xml_settings. $word_landscape_div_end.'
        </body>
        </html>';

 @header('Content-Type: application/msword');
 @header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
 @header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="Party Rate Report.doc"');
 echo $content;

  ?>
```

Here my database:

[image]

Comment: what the hell are you doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick reformat, adding a loop (and assuming the id is an integer):-

```
<?php


    include('dbcon.php');

    if($_GET['id']!='')
    {
        $id=intval($_GET['id']);

        $party_name=mysql_query("select * FROM tb_party Where party_id=$id ");
        if ($party_name_row=mysql_fetch_array($party_name))
        {
            $sample_text1 = $party_name_row['party_name'];
        }

        $word_xmlns = "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
        xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'";

        $word_xml_settings = "<xml><w:WordDocument>
        <w:View>Print</w:View><w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom></w:WordDocument></xml>";

        $word_landscape_style = 
        "@page {size:8.5in 11.0in; margin:0.5in 0.31in 0.42in 0.25in;
        }  div.Section1{page:Section1;}";

        $word_landscape_headinh="{font-size:15px; }";

        $word_landscape_div_imf='
        <img  src="http://silverevents.net/user_image/' .$sample_text1 . '"  
        height="150" width="150"/>';

        $word_landscape_div_start = "<div class='Section1'> ";

        $word_landscape_div_end = "</div>";

        $content = '<html '.$word_xmlns.'>
            <head>
                         <title>Party Rate Report</title>'
                         .$word_xml_settings.'<style type="text/css">
            '.$word_landscape_style.' table,td 
                         {border:1px solid #FFFFFF; width:200px; color:#CCC;} </style>
            </head>
            <body>'.$word_landscape_div_start  . 
                        '<table style="width:500px; color:#000000; 
                        margin:0 0 50px 100px; font-family: Arial Black, Gadget, 
                        sans-serif; font-size:24px;"><tr><td> Party Rate Report </td>
                        </tr></table></br>

            <table style="width:700px;font-size:15px;font-family: 
                         Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif;">

            <tr>

            <td width="180">
                Party Name : '.  $party_name_row['party_name'] . '
            </td>

            <td width="250">
            Address : '.  $party_name_row['party_address'] . '
            </td>

            <td width="150">
            Phone : '.   $party_name_row['phone_no']. '
            </td>
            </tr>


            </table><br/>   
            <table style="width:700px; color:#00000; margin:22px 0 0 0px; 
                         font- family:Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana; 
                        font-size:15px;  border1px solid #666;">
            <tr>
            <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Zone</td>
            <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> 
                         Delivery Mode          
                         </td>
            <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Doc Type </td>
            <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Weight slot </td>
            <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Weight Unit </td>
            <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Flat </td>
            <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;"> Price </td>
            </tr>';


        $party_details="select * 
                        from tb_party_rate_entry
                        where party_id=$id";
        $query_details=mysql_query($party_details);
        while($row_details=mysql_fetch_array($query_details))
        {
            $content .= '<tr>
             <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">' .
                         $row_details['zone_id']. '</td>
                       <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.
                        $row_details['delivery_mode_id'].'
                       </td>
                     <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'. 
                      $row_details['doc_type_id'].'</td>    
                     <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'. 
                       $row_details['weight_slot_id'].'</td>    
                     <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.
                     $row_details['weight_measure_id'].'</td>   
               <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.
                  (($row_details['flat'] != '') ? $row_details['flat'] : ' ').'</td>   
               <td style=" border:1px solid #666; width:300px;">'.   
                $row_details['price' ] . '</td>         
            </tr>';


        }
        $content .=     '</table></br>' . $word_xml_settings. $word_landscape_div_end.'
            </body>
            </html>';

        @header('Content-Type: application/msword');
        @header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
        @header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="Party Rate Report.doc"');
        echo $content;
    }

  ?>
```

Note for new code you probably should switch to using mysqli rather than the php mysql drivers

Comment: sir its giving me the same result as before. Its printing only single first row from database.

Comment: How many rows are there on the table tb_party_rate_entry for the party_id you are searching for? Or are you trying to get the details for all party_id values?

Comment: it has 4-5 rows in my localhost db

Comment: Can you export the details (ie, table definitions and the data) from the 2 tables and put those details in your original post please?

Comment: sir i have update my original post with table details.

Comment: Couple of issues. First is my fault - need to move the close of the table outside the loop. The other problem is that a couple of the closing quotes you have used are a bit odd and php is translating them into something quite strange (for example the one immediately following http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40 ). I have amended my reply to suit.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:

```
while ($row_details=mysql_fetch_array($query_details)) {
    //do row specific code
}
```